# NAudio SineWave

Tags: naudio

using example on the blog i have outputted a sine wave:

```
public class SineWaveProvider32 : WaveProvider32{

    int sample;

    public SineWaveProvider32()
    {
        Frequency = 1000;
        Amplitude = 0.25f; // let's not hurt our ears            
    }

    public float Frequency { get; set; }
    public float Amplitude { get; set; }

    public override int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int sampleCount)
    {
        int sampleRate = WaveFormat.SampleRate;
        for (int n = 0; n < sampleCount; n++)
        {
            buffer[n+offset] = (float)(Amplitude * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * sample * Frequency) / sampleRate));
            sample++;
            if (sample >= sampleRate) sample = 0;
        }
        return sampleCount;
    }
}
```

when i play this sine wave its an endless loop. wondering how i would output a sound with a given length ?

Comment: Do not delete content in this manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sine wave will continue to play so long as Read does not return 0. Read returns the number of samples written to the buffer (and should always be the same as sampleCount as long as you haven't finished). So keep a running total of how many samples you have returned. Once that number is equal to the sample rate, you have played one second of audio.